# UIImage from path or filename in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimage

i have a bunch of images in my App's Documents Directory. i want to load one of them in an UIImage that i have in my view. this is what i do:

```
myImage.image = UIImage(named: "image.jpg") // the file exist but this returns nil
```

I also tried to init the image using:

```
myImage.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath) //this also doesn't work but the path i got starts (at least in the sim) with file://
```

Anyone can suggest something? I'm kinda a noob in iOS programming.

Thanks

EDIT:
imagePath comes from:

```
func getImgPath(name: String) -> String
{
    let documentsDirectory = self.getDocumentsDirectory()
    let fullpath = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(name)
    return fullpath.absoluteString

}
```

Comment: Post the code of `imagePath`

Comment: check whether image is of type jpg .?

Comment: probably `imagePath` is not correct, post the code for that

Comment: i edited the question with the imagePath code.

Comment: myImage.image = UIImage(named: "image.jpg") always write a string in double quotes .

Comment: yes sorry i edit that but i pass a string (that is correct and the file exists) as a variable

Comment: @HakikatSingh It's the same actually

Comment: maybe the name you pass is wrong, try print everything in the path out to check again

Comment: @paper1111 the question is edited now but it wasn't there before

Comment: i print the name and it is right. To be precise the image name is "137.jpg" and in my app documents directory the file exist. I am sure because i constantly check that directory

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This might help

```
let documentDirectory = FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory
let userDomainMask    = FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask
let paths             = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(documentDirectory, userDomainMask, true)
if let dirPath        = paths.first
{
   let imageURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath).appendingPathComponent("name.png")
   let image    = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageURL.path)
   // Do whatever you want with the image
}
```

Comment: This totally helped. Thanks a lot, i'm never going to understand why swift had to be like this... Thanks again!

Comment: Glad that it helped you. Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

Try adding your images under `Assets.xcassets`. Then you'll be able to reference your image by:

```
UIImage(named: 'yourImageName')
```

You can conveniently add images with various size settings.

Comment: i download the images from Internet, is it possible to move them in Assets.xcassets after the download?

Comment: @Andrea well, no... In that case, you'll have to convert your image data to `UIImage` where it downloads.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the path of the image as fowllows:

```
let imagePath = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true).appendingPathComponent("image.jpg")
```

If this doesn't work, check if your file name is correct.

Comment: this is not working. but the image exist and the name is right... i am using the imagePath.absoluteString in the contentsOfFile: intialization of UIImage.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that if you are downloading images from internet means, you need to convert the `URL` to `UIImage`

```
    if let url = URL(string: "your url") {
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
        if let imageData = data {
            if let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                imageView.image = image
            }
        }
    }
```

If i understand your question correct, this will be the answer.

Comment: no. i mention that i download the images only in one comments. The reason i didn't write that in the question is because the App should work without the connection too, so i am downloading the images and then i want to access them only when i need them.

Comment: Okay i understand now. Please refer this [library](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) . Here there are storing images in 'cache' memory. So it will work without connection. Hope this helps.