# An extension which can load image from a web URL and from local directory by file name

Tags: ios, swift

I am using this extension

```
extension UIImage {

    public static func loadFrom(url: URL, completion: @escaping (_ image: UIImage?) -> ()) {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(UIImage(data: data))
                }
            } else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want something which can load from web url as well by image file name stored locally

Local location refers to images picked by `imagePickerController` and then saved to `coreData`, I need to load them into `collection view` from `CoreData`.
Suggest the best way to save and load local images, as web images are working fine.

Local image location:

> file:///Users/abhishek/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E189ACEA-3A22-41C9-94DD-06ACE5A8D16D/data/Containers/Data/Application/96851D78-3BD6-4CAA-83AF-0E752FEF10B1/tmp/542CB563-6233-4C96-9ACA-25984F3CBF98.jpeg

Web URL example is [here](https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535370976884-f4376736ab06?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80)

Comment: What is local URL?

Comment: Loading data from a remote URL with synchronous `Data(contentsOf` is very bad practice, even on a background thread.

Comment: what is that local means cache memory or phone's local gallery or application's resource ?

Comment: local gallery, image saved by imagePickerController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, instead of passing local URL, I filtered out its name and now I am passing the name, made some changes in extention

```
extension UIImage {

    public static func loadFrom(url: String, completion: @escaping (_ image: UIImage?) -> ()) {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(string: url)!) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(UIImage(data: data))
                }
            }
            else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let documentDirectory = FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory
                    let userDomainMask = FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask
                    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(documentDirectory, userDomainMask, true)
                    if let dirPath = paths.first {
                        let imageURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath).appendingPathComponent("\(url)")
                        let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageURL.path)
                        completion(image)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And now it works like a charm

I took help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46072471/11690901)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this. https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage. This library does what you need + it caches images.

Answer (score 1):

```
extension UIImage {

    public static func loadFrom(url: URL, completion: @escaping (_ image: UIImage?) -> ()) {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(UIImage(data: data))
                }
            } else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between your answer and the code in question?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of accepting a `URL` parameter in `loadFrom` method, accept a `String` parameter.

This `String` could be either a `urlString` or the name of an `image` in the `Assets`.

```
extension UIImage {
    public static func loadFrom(urlString: String, completion: @escaping (_ image: UIImage?) -> ()) {
        if let image = UIImage(named: urlString) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(image)
            }
        } else {
            if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
                DispatchQueue.global().async {
                    if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            completion(UIImage(data: data))
                        }
                    } else {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            completion(nil)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, first check if the `image` with name `urlString` exist in the project itself. If not, then create a `URL` from `urlString` and get the `image` from that `URL`.

**Usage:**

```
UIImage.loadFrom(urlString: "imageName") { (image) in
    //add your code here.....
}
UIImage.loadFrom(urlString: "https://www.pexels.com/photo/animal-antenna-biology-butterfly-2395264/") { (image) in
    //add your code here.....
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but according to my used case I will pass only two url to this function, a web url (passed by google image search) and one from photo library (passed by imagePickerController). 
I don't have to load anything from image asset
My url is like 
file:///Users/abhishek/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E189ACEA-3A22-41C9-94DD-06ACE5A8D16D/data/Containers/Data/Application/96851D78-3BD6-4CAA-83AF-0E752FEF10B1/tmp/542CB563-6233-4C96-9ACA-25984F3CBF98.jpeg
in which folder before '/tmp/' always changes on restart of app

Comment: `imagePickerController` with directly give you the image in its delegate method. You won't need to get the `image` separately with `URL`.

Comment: actually on picking an image from photo library I want to save it in core data, and a collection view will load images from core data.

Comment: Then you can simply save the retrieved image in CoreData as `data`. No need to save the path to it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it was my mistake I din't explained you the whole functionality.
In coreData I have to save images selected by user, and user can either choose from Google images(which will return web url) or from Photo Library

Comment: That's okay. No issues. Glad that you resolved the issue. Happy coding..